# Can i use a window like the unity shortcuts window to show a message?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, indicator-message

Unity shortcut window appear when holding the super key on the keyboard:
[image]
Wow a pretty good look glassy transparent window.
So Is there any way to show a welcome message in a window like it to me when i login and wait 5 sec then disappear, cause that would be awesome ?